# Error Build Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I found this error when create new project on android studio, i dont know what happen to my setting.
Anyone can explain how to resolve this error on android studio?

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>       This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>       For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>       Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>       Please read the following process output to find out more:
>       -----------------------
>       15:46:59.823 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts:
>   [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m,
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
>       15:47:00.535 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
>       15:47:00.704 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon -
>   DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0b3e62eb-bb9a-4941-8e1f-b2a97729aa65,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/mnafian/.gradle/daemon,pid=2506,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
>       15:47:00.741 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating
>   lastActivityAt to 1429865220741
>       15:47:00.801 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   IP addresses for network interface en1
>       15:47:00.802 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this
>   a loopback interface? false
>       15:47:00.803 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this
>   a multicast interface? true
>       15:47:00.804 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   remote address /fe80:0:0:0:1e65:9dff:fec2:44fb%5
>       15:47:00.805 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   remote address /192.168.1.68
>       15:47:00.806 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   remote multicast interface en1
>       15:47:00.807 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   IP addresses for network interface lo0
>       15:47:00.808 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this
>   a loopback interface? true
>       15:47:00.809 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this
>   a multicast interface? true
>       15:47:00.810 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory]
>   Ignoring remote address on loopback interface /fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
>       15:47:00.811 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
>       15:47:00.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   loopback address /127.0.0.1
>       15:47:00.814 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding
>   loopback multicast interface lo0
>       15:47:00.840 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector]
>   Listening on [11131ac7-8dd5-45e7-b4ed-7fe10d94538a port:49260,
>   addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]].
>       15:47:00.845 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon starting at: Fri Apr 24 15:47:00 WIB 2015, with address:
>   [11131ac7-8dd5-45e7-b4ed-7fe10d94538a port:49260,
>   addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]]
>       15:47:00.846 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertising
>   the daemon address to the clients:
>   [11131ac7-8dd5-45e7-b4ed-7fe10d94538a port:49260,
>   addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]]
>       15:47:00.847 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertised
>   daemon context:
>   DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0b3e62eb-bb9a-4941-8e1f-b2a97729aa65,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/mnafian/.gradle/daemon,pid=2506,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
>       15:47:00.848 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Storing
>   daemon address: [11131ac7-8dd5-45e7-b4ed-7fe10d94538a port:49260,
>   addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], context:
>   DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0b3e62eb-bb9a-4941-8e1f-b2a97729aa65,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/mnafian/.gradle/daemon,pid=2506,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
>       15:47:00.919 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire
>   exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
>       15:47:00.928 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
>       15:47:00.978 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on
>   daemon addresses registry.
>       15:47:00.999 [ERROR] [system.err] 
>       15:47:01.000 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>       15:47:01.002 [ERROR] [system.err] 
>       15:47:01.002 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
>       15:47:01.003 [ERROR] [system.err] javcs   ng/Objec
>       15:47:01.004 [ERROR] [system.err] 
>       15:47:01.005 [ERROR] [system.err] * Try:
>       15:47:01.006 [ERROR] [system.err] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
>   output.
>       15:47:01.011 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry]
>   Removing daemon address: [11131ac7-8dd5-45e7-b4ed-7fe10d94538a
>   port:49260, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]]
>       15:47:01.013 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire
>   exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
>       15:47:01.014 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
>       15:47:01.015 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on
>   daemon addresses registry.
>       15:47:01.017 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire
>   exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
>       15:47:01.018 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
>       15:47:01.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on
>   daemon addresses registry.

I deleted .gradle in my user home folder and thats error still happen. I am use OSX 10.10.3 and Android studio 1.1.0

Comment: Please try in Android Studio:
File ->Invalidate Caches/Restart ->Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @NafianWildana I faced this previously . Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **First Close your android studio**
2. **Try deleting your .gradle  directory.**
3. **Now Open Android Studio & open the project**
4. **Synchronize the project gradle now android studio will create again .gradle directory under the user.**

I hope it will help you

**Edit**

If it does not work, You can re-install your **`#Android Studio`** .

Comment: Error still happen, and i'm very frustrating because i can't create new project.

Comment: Update your android studio 1.2 RC

Comment: Solve, I was uninstall AS and clear all cache and setting and try to fresh Install AS.. but thx for your answer.